# Is there any way to out put the "mac address and IP address" into a GUI text box?

Tags: python, user-interface, tkinter, listbox, scapy

```
import sys
import threading
import time
import tkinter
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import ttk
import scapy.all as scapy
from scapy.layers.l2 import Ether, ARP
import re
import numpy
```

#====GUI=====

```
 from tkinter import Entry

 gui = Tk()
 gui.title('Network Scanner')
 gui.geometry("400x600+20+20")
```

#====delete Function====

```
 def delete():
 listbox.delete(0,tkinter.END)
```

#====scanning Function====

```
 def startScan():


 ip_add_range_pattern = re.compile("^(?:[0-9]{1,3}\.){3}[0-9]{1,3}/[0-9]*$")


 while True:
  ip_add_range_entered = L22.get()

  if ip_add_range_pattern.search(ip_add_range_entered):
   l1 = Label(gui, text=f"{ip_add_range_entered} is a valid ip address range")
   l1.place(x=16, y=175)
   break
  else:
   l2 = Label(gui, text=f"{ip_add_range_entered} is NOT a valid ip address range")
   l2.place(x=16, y=175)
   break

 ans,unans = scapy.srp(Ether(dst="ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff") / 
ARP(pdst=ip_add_range_entered), timeout=2)
 ans.summary(lambda s, r: r.sprintf("%Ether.src% %ARP.psrc%"))



 display = ans.summary(lambda s,r: r.sprintf("%ARP.psrc%"))

 listbox.insert(0,display)
```

#===Colors=====

```
m1c ='#00ee00'
bgc ='#222222'
dbg ='#000000'
fgc ='#111111'

gui.tk_setPalette(background=bgc,
foreground=m1c, activeBackground=fgc,
 activeForeground=bgc, highlightColor=m1c,
 highlightBackground=m1c)
```

#===Labels====

```
L11 = Label(gui, text="Network Scanner", font=("arial", 16, 'underline'))
L11.place(x=16, y=10)

L21 = Label(gui, text="Target IP: ")
L21.place(x=16, y=90)


L22 = Entry(gui, text = "Target IP:")
L22.place(x=70, y=90)
L22.insert(0,"192.168.1.1/24")

L23 = Label(gui,text="(Ex. 192.168.1.1/24)")
L23.place(x=80,y=110)
```

#====IP results====#

```
frame = Frame(gui)
frame.place(x=16,y=200, height= 165, width=370)
listbox = Listbox(frame, width=60,height=10)
listbox.place(x=0,y=0)
listbox.bind('<<ListboxSelect>>')
```

#===scroll bar====

```
scrollbar1 = Scrollbar(frame)
scrollbar1.pack(side=RIGHT,fill=Y)
listbox.config(yscrollcommand=scrollbar1.set)
scrollbar1.config(command=listbox.yview)

scrollbar2 = Scrollbar(frame,orient='horizontal')
scrollbar2.pack(side=BOTTOM,fill=X)
listbox.config(xscrollcommand=scrollbar2.set)
scrollbar2.config(command=listbox.xview)
```

#====Buttons=======

```
B11 = Button(gui,text= "Start Scan",command=startScan)
B11.place(x=16,y=450, width=170)

B11 = Button(gui,text= "Clear",command=delete)
B11.place(x=200,y=450, width=170)
```

#=====Start GUI=====

```
gui.mainloop()'''
```

---

The main issue I'm having is when I run the:

**ans.summary(lambda s, r: r.sprintf("%Ether.src% %ARP.psrc%"))-> this prints to the console**

Is there a way to make this print into my listbox instead, within the gui?

I have already tried "listbox.insert(0,display)" but I don't think this actually assigns any data to the variable "display"

Comment: Please post an [mvce](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) to help us help you!

Comment: You will more likely get answers if you reduce your problem statement as much as possible.  Here we don't need all the GUI stuff,  basically you can just state that `ans.summary(lambda s,r: r.sprintf("%ARP.psrc%"))` prints something to the standard output while you want to store this in a string...